# Why is the compiler saying the variable is dropped while still borrowed if the borrower is already dropped?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a question about lifetimes. I have the following code:

```rust
async move {
    let futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
    let subscriptions = database.get_subscribers_for(&msg).await?;
    for notifier in notifiers.iter() {
        futures.push(notifier.notify(&msg, &subscriptions));
    }
    let results = futures.collect::<Vec<Result<()>>>().await;
    results
        .into_iter()
        .filter(Result::is_err)
        .for_each(|result| error!("Error sending notification: {}", result.unwrap_err()));
    Ok(())
}
```

Signature from nofity:

```rust
async fn notify(&self, msg: &Notification, subs: &[Subscriptions]) -> Result<()>
```

I'm getting an error saying `subscriptions` might not live long enough and that `subscriptions` can be still be borrowed when dropped.
How can it be if the collect from the `futures` take the value from the futures and then I call `into_iter` which consumes all entries?
So basically the `futures` will be dropped before `subscriptions`. Am I understanding it wrong?

If I set the code like this, forcing the futures to be in a separate block, it compiles:

```rust
async move {
    let subscriptions = database.get_subscribers_for(&msg).await?;
    {
        let futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
        for notifier in notifiers.iter() {
            futures.push(notifier.notify(&msg, &subscriptions));
        }
        let results = futures.collect::<Vec<Result<()>>>().await;
        results
            .into_iter()
            .filter(Result::is_err)
            .for_each(|result| error!("Error sending notification: {}", result.unwrap_err()));
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Compiler message:

```
error[E0597]: `subscriptions` does not live long enough
  --> src/notification/mod.rs:57:52
   |
57 |                 futures.push(notifier.notify(&msg, &subscriptions));
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
65 |         })
   |         -
   |         |
   |         `subscriptions` dropped here while still borrowed
   |         borrow might be used here, when `futures` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `FuturesUnordered`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

Comment: Please add the full error message from the compiler to your question.

Comment: [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c534210d413e93c792ba8ff759b3ebd). Note: to get it to compile it's sufficient to reverse the order of `let futures = ...` and `let subsciptions = ...` lines.

Comment: I **think** the problem is that you are only considering the scenario when the code runs to completion, but the compiler also considers other scenarios. For example, what if there is a panic before the call to `futures.collect()` (e.g. during the loop)? In that case first `subscriptions` will be dropped, then `futures`. Since futures inside `futures` contain borrows from `subscriptions`, that means their `Drop` impls will observe dangling references.

Comment: @user4815162342 it makes sense. I believe you can write as answer